# How to get the dimensions of an image from an URL?

Tags: c++, boost, png

I want to get the dimensions of an image from an URL, but I don't want to download le full image.
For example, for a PNG image :

- The width can be read from the 16th byte to the 20th
- The height can be read from the 20th to the 24th

So I want to download / read only the first 24 bytes.
Is it possible? How? Maybe by using `Boost`, but I don't have any idea how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards.

Comment: You can [specify a byte range in an HTTP `get` request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35).

Comment: @Jerry : Good idea, I'll try to do that way.

Comment: @Irrational Person: I only downloaded the full image, then read the first bytes and deduce the dimensions. I've searched how to download only a part of an image, but without any result.

Comment: @vincentp: JerryCoffin told you how to do it - send an HTTP request that has a `Range: bytes=16-23` header specifying the starting offset and number of bytes to retrieve. If the server supports range requests, it will send a `206 Partial Content` reply containing just the bytes you requested, otherwise it will send a normal `200 OK` reply containing the full image.

Comment: In a JPEG image, the size can be far into the stream. (You say PNG for example).